# zsh alias for dot (graphviz)

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh, graphviz

I am trying to create an zsh alias that when called as:

```
dott file.dot
```

would return a file.png file. my failed attempt so far was:

```
alias dott=dott() { dot -Tpng "$.dot" -o "$.png" ; }
```

but that doesn't work.

My approach so far is not perfect but works:

```
 dott() { dot -Tpng "$@" -o "$@.png" ; }
```

only thing left is that it will have file.dot.png but that is acceptable. if you know how to get rid of the .dot please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd simply write a function, e.g.

```
function dott {
   dot -Tpng "$1" "$(echo $1|sed 's/dot$/png/')"
}
```

and then call it like it was a program

```
dott infile.dot
```

Comment: I would suggest using the *parameter expansion* `${1%.dot}.png` instead of utilizing `sed` in *command substitution*. It does not need external commands, works with POSIX-conformant shells (`bash`, `dash`, `zsh`, …) and adds ".png" even if `$1` does not end in "dot" (which could otherwise lead to the original file being overwritten).

Comment: @Adaephon: nice, wasn't even aware of that working in anything *but* zsh, so I considered that to be highly specific knowledge. Great!
Would you mind adding your own answer, so I can get something to upvote :) ?

Answer (score 3):

As you need to use arguments multiple times and at other places than the end of the command, aliases will not work. Instead you should use a function:

```
dott() {
    dot -T png "$1" -o "${1%.dot}.png"
}
```

You can than use it with

```
dott file.dot
```

#### Explanation:

- `dott()` declares a function named `dott` in a way that should work with most POSIX-conformant shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `dash`, …). Some shells (`bash`, `zsh`) also allow function definition with their own `function` keyword: `function dott`. This works not everywhere, for example `dash`.
- `{...}` braces a list of commands called *compound command*, it will be executed when the command is called.
- `$1` is the first argument you pass to the function.
- `"$1"` the double quotes around `$1` are needed in case the argument contains white spaces. **Note:** In `zsh` the quotes are not needed, unless the shell option `SH_WORD_SPLIT` is set (which is not the case by default).
- `${1%.dot}`: If the the value of `$1` ends with *`.dot`* this is substituted by value with the *`.dot`* removed (*`file.dot`* → *`file`*). If it does not end in *`.dot`* the value is substituted unchanged (*`file.dat`* → *`file.dat`*). This works in all POSIX-conformant shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `dash`, ...).
- `"${1%.dot}.png"` appends *`.png`* to the substituded output filename, whether it originally ended in *`.dot`* or not (*`file.dot`* → *`file.png`*, *`file.dat`* -> *`file.dat.png`*). Again, the double quotes are needed to account for possible white spaces.

---

If you often need to convert multiple files, you could extend the function to allow for multiple filenames:

```
dott() {
    for file in "$@"; do
        dot -Tpng "$file" -o "${file%.dot}.png"
    done
}
```

This can be used with

```
dott file1.dot file2.dot file3.dot
```

Of course it also works for single files.

#### Explanation (only changes):

- `$@` is the complete list of all positional parameters passed to the function.
- `"$@"` expands in a way that each parameter expands as a separate *word*. It is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`. **Note:** the double quotes are optional in `zsh`, *even if* the option `SH_WORD_SPLIT` is set.
- `for file in "$@"; do COMMAND-LIST; done` runs `COMMAND-LIST` for each element of `"$@"`. Inside the loop the current element can be access by the name `$file`.